# Overfitting problem with my validation data

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am applying CNN model using keras. I fed the details coefficients of discrete wavelet transform level 5 as a 2D array of size (5,3840) into the CNN.I would like to use CNN to predict seizure.The problem is my network is overfitting. Any suggestion on how to solve overfitting problem.

```
    input_shape=(1, 22, 5, 3844)
    model = Sequential()
    #C1
    model.add(Conv3D(16, (22, 5, 5), strides=(1, 2, 2), padding='same',activation='relu',data_format= "channels_first", input_shape=input_shape))
    model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(1, 2, 2),data_format= "channels_first",  padding='same'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    #C2
    model.add(Conv3D(32, (1, 3, 3), strides=(1, 1,1), padding='same',data_format= "channels_first",  activation='relu'))#incertezza se togliere padding
    model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(1,2, 2),data_format= "channels_first", ))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())

     #C3
    model.add(Conv3D(64, (1,3, 3), strides=(1, 1,1), padding='same',data_format= "channels_first",  activation='relu'))#incertezza se togliere padding
    model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(1,2, 2),data_format= "channels_first",padding='same' ))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(256, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

    opt_adam = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.00001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt_adam, metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 frequently used *regularization* techniques to avoid over-fitting:

1. *L1 & L2 Regularization* : Regularizers allow to apply penalties on layer parameters    or layer activity during optimization. These penalties are incorporated in the loss function that the network optimizes.

   ```
   from keras import regularizers
   model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=64,
             kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01),
             activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.01)))
   ```
2. *Dropout* : Dropout consists in randomly setting a fraction rate of input units to 0 at each update during training time, which helps prevent 
   over-fitting.

   ```
   from keras.layers import Dropout
   model.add(Dense(60, input_dim=60, activation='relu'))
   model.add(Dropout(rate=0.2))
   model.add(Dense(30, activation='relu'))
   model.add(Dropout(rate=0.2))
   model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
   ```

Also you can use *Early-Stopping* to interrupt training when the validation loss isn't decreasing anymore

```
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=2)
model.fit(x, y, validation_split=0.2, callbacks=[early_stopping])
```

Additionally, you might wanna consider *Data-Augmentation* techniques such as cropping, padding, and horizontal flipping. With these techniques, you can increase the diversity of your data available for your training model, without actually collecting new data. So you can capture data invariance and reduce over-fitting

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    featurewise_center=True,
    featurewise_std_normalization=True,
    rotation_range=20,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32),
                    steps_per_epoch=len(x_train) / 32, epochs=epochs)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution it was really helped me.

Comment: @Abduallah Deliogullari I wonder if you can help me in how to save weights .

Comment: @gigi can you create a new question? So I can add extensive explanation over this issue

Comment: Done , I create a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Steps to remove overfitting:

- Reduce the number of neural units in your hidden layers

I do not think you need softmax layer after a sigmoid layer. Probably your model is overfitting because of that.

Try replacing sigmoid layer with a dense layer with relu activation and output (n, 2) followed by your softmax layer.

Your learning rate is very low as well, which suggests that your model will take long to find the global minima hence underfit, but that is not happening here. This solidifies my suspicion that sigmoid layer is the cause.